# Probability of 6 Independent Events Occurring

Tags: probability

There is a $10\%$, $5\%$, $39\%$, $20\%$, $24\%$ and $2\%$ chance of $6$ independent events occurring. However, there is a $50\%$ chance that only the events that the $39\%$ chance and $2\%$ chance events will occur.

What are the chances of these $6$ independent events when the $50\%$ chance comes into play?

Comment: This is not clear to me. Do you mean that 50% of the time we know that either event $C$ (39%) or $F$ (2%) (but not the rest) will happen? What about the other 50%, are $A$ to $F$ possible or just $A,B,D$ or $E$?

Comment: 50% of the time, only events C and F are possible.

Comment: And the other 50% are $C$ and $F$ possible or not?

Comment: Yes, with a 39% and 2% chance to occur respectively along with events A, B, D and E at their respective chances.

Answer (score 1):

Lets label these events $A,B,C,D,E$ and $F$. We have that $50\%$ of the time ($H$) either $C$ or $F$ happen. The rest of the time ($T$) any result is possible. As $A,B,D$ and $E$ are only possible $50\%$ of the time, we have

\begin{array}
\text{Event} & P(X|H) & P(X|T) & P(X) \\
A & 0 & 10\% & \frac{410}{8200}\\
B & 0 &  5\% & \frac{205}{8200}\\
C & \frac{39}{39+2} & 39\% & \frac{5499}{8200}\\
D & 0 & 20\% & \frac{820}{8200}\\
E & 0 & 24\% & \frac{984}{8200} \\
F & \frac{2}{39+2} & 2\% & \frac{282}{8200} \\
\end{array}

where $P(X)=\frac{1}{2}P(X|H)+\frac{1}{2}P(X|T).$

Answer (score 0):

Let's call our events $A, B, C, D, E$. The probability of an event $X\in\{A, B, C, D, E\}$ when only the two events occurs is $$P_2(X)=\cases{\frac{P_5(X)}{P_5(C)+P_5(E)}, X\in\{C,E\}\\0, X\in\{A,B,D\}}$$
Then $$P(X)=0.5P_2(X)+0.5P_5(X)$$